# PDFbox remove color from PDF not showing the color behind it

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I'm facing an issue that I'm drawing colors on top of colors and when removing the top color a white color appears and not the second color (the color behind the removed color).

For example,

Here I'm drawing 4 squares on the top left with no spot colors, and drawing 3 squares in the middle with spot colors.

[image]

the top left contains 4 squares ordered from the behind to the top:

1- a square with width and height 100, color 1,0,0,0

2- a square with width and height 85, color 0,1,0,0

3- a square with width and height 60, color 0,0,1,0

4- a square with width and height 35, color 0,0,0,1

And in the middle, the 3 squares ordered from the behind to the top:

1- a square with width and height 100, spot color color1 255,0,0

2- a square with width and height 60, spot color color2 0,255,0

3- a square width width and height 30, spot color color3 0,0,255

When I remove one of the colors like color 3 a white color appears instead of the color behind the blue which is green.

Also when removing the color on the behind, a white background appears and not the transparent background.

What is the issue and how I can solve it?

Thanks

Comment: *"I remove one of the colors"* - What do you mean by that? Do you replace e.g. the CMYK colorspace used in the top squares by a custom colorspace having only CMY?

Comment: I mean that I unchecked it so it should not appear in the output pdf

Comment: How do you "uncheck a color" in PDFBox? PDFBox is a PDF library after all. You probably should show your code.

Comment: No, I drew the squares with PDFbox and created the file, I unchecked the spot color by Adobe Acrobat Pro DC

Comment: I found a solution which is to use the overprint property, do you know how to use it, I could find a useful description for it